# Select List from Dictionary giving error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, selectlist

I create a viewbag as below

```
Dictionary<string, long> actlist = new Dictionary<string, long>();

foreach()
{
 //filling the dictionary
}

 ViewBag.act_type = new SelectList(actlist, "Value", "Key");
```

In the view call the view bag as below

```
@Html.DropDownList("acttype", new SelectList(ViewBag.act_type, "Value","Key"))
```

It's giving an error as below

> SelectList does not contain a property with the name 'Key'

What I am missing here?

Comment: It would need to be `@Html.DropDownList("acttype", new SelectList(ViewBag.act_type, "Value","Text"))` But its already a `SelectList`, so its pointless extra overhead to convert it to `SelectList` again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ya thanks..sort it out `@Html.DropDownList("acttype", (SelectList)(ViewBag.act_type))`

Comment: Great. Now move from beginner, and start using a view model (which will contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActTypeOptions` so its `@Html.DropDownList("acttype", Model.ActTypeOptions)` - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks..implemented the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the SelectList twice. When you set drop down list, pass the SelectList that you already created.

Add the dictionary to the ViewBag

```
ViewBag.act_type = actlist;
```

Then create the SelectList

```
@Html.DropDownList("acttype", new SelectList(ViewBag.act_type, "Value","Key"))
```

In what you have, you are trying to create a new SelectList from first one.

Comment: `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched`

Comment: i got the answer..a slight change in ur first code
`@Html.DropDownList("acttype", (SelectList)(ViewBag.act_type))`